# Wait for method to finish an AutoResetEvent without blocking UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Sorry if this is quite similar to other questions, but I just can't make this work..

How do I run this code, without blocking my ui when calling `wh.WaitOne()`?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some work
        MessageBox.Show("Before pause");

        string someVar = activate();

        MessageBox.Show("After pause");
        //some other work which should only run when 'string someVar = activate();' above succeeds
    }

    private string activate()
    {
        wh.WaitOne();
        return textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wh.Set();
    }
}
```

I know I could put the `wh.WaitOne()` inside a new thread, but `return textbox1.Text` would get executed right after the thread started without waiting for it to finish. Is there a simple way of waiting for the thread containing `wh.WaitOne()` to finish perhaps?

Comment: No.  Just NO.  Do NOT wait in a GUI event-handler.  Use messaging, ie Invoke/BeginInvoke, to signal thread events and act on them.

Comment: Search for questions on BackgroundWorker, that is a better approach based on your requirements.

Comment: I think what you want is an awaitable AutoResetEvent such as [this one from Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent).

Comment: Wouldn't the line `return textBox1.Text;` get executed right after I start a BackgroundWorker?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [awaitable `AutoResetEvent` from Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent), you can do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly AsyncAutoResetEvent wh = new AsyncAutoResetEvent(false);

    public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some work
        MessageBox.Show("Before pause");

        string someVar = await activate();

        MessageBox.Show("After pause");
        //some other work which should only run when 'string someVar = activate();' above succeeds
    }

    private async Task<string> activate()
    {
        await wh.WaitAsync();
        return textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wh.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just checking that out, this looks good! But which namespace do I use or how do I "install" AsyncAutoResetEvent?

Comment: I don't recommend pulling a library just for this purpose. If there are other uses, then yes AsyncEx is a good library to have. Instead I recommend [Stephen toub's AsyncAutoResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266923.aspx) which is easy to use.

Comment: @GoffiH. See Sriram's reply, but if you did want to install the AsyncEx library you just go to Project | Manage NuGet Packages and browse for "Nito.AsyncEx" and click the install button. (It's the library that's had > 100K downloads.) Check out https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/README.md